# Can't delete vertices in Maya

Tags: 3d, maya

I've switched from C4D and Blender to Maya and bumped into few problems. One of this problems is why sometimes I can't delete vertices?
[image]

I've tried Delete, Backspace, Ctrl+Delete, Ctrl+Backspace, Shift+RMB -> Delete Vertex, Mesh -> Delete Vertex. Even deleted history of this mesh. And it's still not deleting.

Comment: Delete inbound edgds first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch to face selection mode, select and delete the face.

You need at least 3 points to support a surface. Deleting the third point will confuse maya.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot and explain a little bit better what you mean?  What does "confuse" mean? Resulting in an error message? Unexpected results?

Comment: @Kurt maya wont just let you do it. It will just result in nothing happening. Default delete just deletes freestanding vertices, since a triangle allready has pruned possible freedoms no deletion will happen. Delete the face or delete edges, they have a higher priority. This is done so that you dont delete structure by mistake.